# How to generate .yml file from Ruby on Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, yaml, gitlab-ci.yml

I would like generate the following result in a .yml file from Ruby on Rails:

```
include:
  - template: ./my_folder/my_file.txt
```

But I am generating the following result with single quote (''):

```
include:
- 'template: ./my_folder/my_file.txt'
```

I have tried generate the .yml file with this ruby code:

```
my_variable = {"include" => ["template: ./my_folder/my_file.txt"]}
```

Comment: This YAML does not even make sense. `-` is used to create a list in YAML. Don't you actually want a dictionary instead of an array of useless strings? Also the quotes don't matter. Both will have the same result after being parsed.

Comment: It's far from clear why you're expressed the inner array as some kind of string, but the YAML encoder is doing exactly what you've asked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would do this:

```
my_variable = { "include" => [{ "template" => "./my_folder/my_file.txt" }] }
my_variable.to_yaml
# ---
# include:                                
# - template: "./my_folder/my_file.txt"
```

Answer (score 0):

```
my_variable = {"include" => ["template: ./my_folder/my_file.txt"]}
                             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

The Array contains a String, not a Hash. It will produce a YAML array with a single string value, not an array with a key/value pair.

Either you have a typo in your data, or you need to split the values in the Array on `:` to produce a Hash.